# How to enter in Data Form in protected sheet

Tags: excel, forms, protected, worksheet

I tried searching for a solution for this but everything seems to point to VBA, which I'm totally clueless about. I tried their solutions but I'm not really getting it so I'm asking it here.

I've created a sheet that allows other users in our company to enter data into a Data Form. Here's a sample: [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oVZW.png)

Is it possible to allow them to enter data while the worksheet is protected? I just don't want anyone messing with the formatting or the formulas in the sheet. So can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can select manually which cells should be locked in a sheet and which not.
Simply leave the cells to which the data form is writing unlocked and it would be ok.

[Lock or unlock specific cells - support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a):

> By default, protecting a worksheet locks all cells so none of them are editable. To enable some cell editing, while leaving other cells locked, it's possible to unlock all the cells. You can lock only specific cells and ranges before you protect the worksheet and, optionally, enable specific users to edit only in specific ranges of a protected sheet.

Comment: Yeah but I think it would be better if after one user enters data into a row, that row gets locked, and no one else can edit it aside from me.